# How to select particular columns from Datatable and insert into other Datatable in web API using linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, webapi

How to select particular columns in datatable and insert into other datatable . If there are 5 columns like ID, Name, PhNumber, Address,Salary  in a Datatable I want to select only ID, Name, PhNumber columns from the Datatable and insert into other containing ID, Name, PhNumber as only columns present in the Datatable in web API using linq Query.

I am trying to insert the specific columns from one Datatable and insert into other Datatable. I tried converting the 1st dataTable to list and inserting specific values from list to 2nd dataTable. is there any way to directly insert the specific columns from one Datatable and insert into other Datatable .

Comment: Is the other table already an entity?

Comment: The simplest option would be to call `ToTable` on the `DefaultView` of the original `DataTable`. That will create a new `DataTable` and allow you to specify the columns to include. This doesn't use LINQ but there's no point using a LINQ query if there's a simpler option.

Comment: 1. Copy the datatable into new datatable. 2. Remove columns from new datatable